# How do I relate Grab Strength and Grab Tear to the real world?

Tags: terminology, strength

I'm looking at a spec sheet for a high density polyethylene woven fabric and I'm seeing the following parameters on it

> Tensile Grab Strength: Warp 155 / Weft 170 - tested ASTM D-5034-09
>   Grab Tear: Warp 30 / Weft 25 - tested ASTM D-751

I understand how warp and weft are the horizontal and vertical so clearly they're running these tests twice, once for each dimension, but I tried reading the papers on the tests that were run and they were quite dense (no pun intended) and I quickly got confused.

How can I translate this into something I can use? Is there a standard unit these are in? What is the difference between grab strength and grab tear?

I'm putting my products in these bags and I need to understand what these terms mean!